# Foundation 5 modal not working

Tags: javascript, css, zurb-foundation

I'm sure I'm making a silly mistake but it took me hours and I couldn't find any solution for my problem. Everything seems ok but not working. I'm using Foundation 5 reveal. But modal window does not show. Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<a class="openModal" href="#" data-reveal-id="imagemodal"><img src="image.jpg" /></a>
<div id="imagemodal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>Modal</div>
```

I've also included the following js files in body tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).foundation();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/foundation/foundation.reveal.js"></script>
```

Any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: What happens if you put the call to foundation.reveal.js before you call `$(document).foundation();`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the call to foundation.reveal.js before you call `$(document).foundation();`.

I'm pretty sure this is because `$(document).foundation();` initiates only those modules that have been specified *prior* to it, something that [Foundation doesn't make clear in its notes](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascript.html).

> Foundation offers you options to customize plugin initialization. By default, calling $('#scope').foundation(); will initialize all available plugins on the page.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add this piece of simple, near bare-bones modal markup, I spent nearly 4 hours last night getting it right, I don't think there's much out there to deal with these reveal-modal issues

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.reveal.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/foundation.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" class="button" data-reveal-id="myNormal">reveal modal</a>
<div class="reveal-modal" id="myNormal" data-reveal>
  Modal
  <a class="close-reveal-modal">close</a>
</div>
<script>
  $(document).foundation();
</script>
</body>
```

I hope this is of any help for future visitors.

Comment: Making sure to do  $(document).foundation(); after the dialog solved my problem!